# Reduce to count elements in a dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, reduce

I'm trying to count the elements of my dictionary. The dictionary is of type [EKCalendar: ReminderList] where ReminderList is a class with a list property. I want to go through the dictionary and add up the count of all these lists.

My dictionary is in the property `self?.reminderListsStructure.structure`.

```
let numberOfElements = self?.reminderListsStructure.structure.reduce(0) {
    accumulator, nextValue in
    return accumulator.list.count + nextValue.list.count  
    // COMPILE ERROR: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
}
```

Comment: Your `accumulator` begins with 0 (and `Int`). Try: `return accumulator + nextValue.list.count`

Comment: Has your question been satisfied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let count = reminderListsStructure.structure.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.1.list.count }
```

Something like this. Not enough info though, so I'm not 100% sure it works.

Answer (score 3):

I think [`flatMap`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/SequenceType/#comment-func--flatmap-s_-sequencetype_-self-generator-element-throws-s) is a more appropriate choice here:

```
let input = [
    1: [1],
    2: [1, 2],
    3: [1, 2, 3],
    4: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    5: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
]

let output = input.values.flatMap{$0}.count //15
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `reduce` a dictionary, the element type is a tuple of the Key and Value types, so you can use:

```
dictionary.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.1.list.count }
```

Or, you can get just the values from the dictionary and reduce that:

```
dictionary.values.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.list.count }
```

Note that since Dictionary.values returns a lazy iterator, there's not really a huge cost to using it.

Answer (score 0):

More simple and clear way goes like this,

```
var dict = ["x" : 1 , "y" : 2, "z" : 3]

let count = dict.reduce(0, { x, element  in

    //maybe here some condition
    //if(element.value > 1){return x}

    return x + 1
})
```